# Retain the latest file sets in a directory for a given file pattern

Tags: bash, shell, sed, ftp

I have multiple set of files in a ftp folder and each set contains a text and a marker file.
Here I need to get the latest set of files having below file pattern from a given directory based on its arrival time.

File format:

```
<FileName>_<FileID>_<Date>_<TimeStamp>.csv
<FileName>_<FileID>_<Date>_<TimeStamp>.mrk
```

File1 has three sets coming at different times:

```
file1_123_20180306_654321.csv
file1_123_20180306_654321.mrk

file1_123_20180306_866321.csv
file1_123_20180306_866321.mrk

file1_123_20180306_976321.csv
file1_123_20180306_976321.mrk
```

File2 has two sets coming at different times:

```
file2_456_20180306_277676.csv
file2_456_20180306_277676.mrk

file2_456_20180306_788988.csv
file2_456_20180306_788988.mrk
```

If it's a single file I'm able to do the below command but in case if its a set I need help.

```
ls -t *123*.mrk | head -1
ls -t *123*.csv | head -1
```

I need to retain only the latest set of files (from file1 and file2) and move the other files into a different folder.

Expected output:

```
file1_123_20180306_976321.csv
file1_123_20180306_976321.mrk
file2_456_20180306_788988.csv
file2_456_20180306_788988.mrk
```

How would I do this using shell or python2.6? Any help is much appreciated.
If a more or less exact answer already exists to this question please point to that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this `awk` to get the latest file entry for each set from your two files:

```
printf '%s\0' *_*_*_*.csv *_*_*_*.mrk |
awk -v RS='\0' -v ORS='\0' -F '[_.]' 'NF{a[$1,$2,$3,$NF]=$0}
   END{for (i in a) print a[i]}' |
xargs -0 -I {} echo mv '{}' /dest/dir
```

**Output:**

```
mv file2_456_20180306_788988.csv /dest/dir
mv file1_123_20180306_976321.mrk /dest/dir
mv file1_123_20180306_976321.csv /dest/dir
mv file2_456_20180306_788988.mrk /dest/dir
```

When you're satisfied with the output, you can remove `echo` before `mv` command to move these files into a destination directory.

Comment: Thanks @@Anubhava. I will try this out. Btw, could you please explain on what you are doing here as I'm still figuring it out? :)

Comment: `awk` command breaks each line using `_` or `.` as delimiter. This gives us `<FileName>` as `$1`, `<FileID>` as `$2`, `<Date>` as `$3` and extension as `$NF` inside `awk` command. `a[$1,$2,$3,$NF]=$0` uses `$1,$2,$3,$NF` as key of the array `a` and `$0` is full line that makes it value part. Value part gets overwritten every time this we get last entry for a given key in array `a` that we are printing in `END` block. `xargs` is just doing `mv` command on each of that entry.

Comment: I placed all the files in a directory and ran the `awk` command. It throws the following error `awk: cmd. line:2: fatal: cannot open file file1 for reading (No such file or directory)`. Am i missing anything here??

Comment: I can only pass `FileID (123,456) and Date (20180306)` for pattern matching.

Comment: Sorry, may be I didn't explain it properly. I put `File1` just to differentiate files but I need to pass the pattern as the input something like `*123*20180306*`

Comment: Thanks @@Anubhava!!